# Coturn Load balancing on Azure

Tags: webrtc, peerjs, azure-load-balancer, coturn, simplewebrtc

I have hosted Turn server on azure Linux VM using coturn, but I am facing problem to achieve high scalability.
How I can deploy coturn server on Azure? Is there any way to use Azure load balancer for coturn server ?